# Oracle NVL invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0) databases, one of which returns `'ok'` for the following query (using SQL Developer 3.2.20.10), whereas the other results in `ORA-01722: invalid number`:

```
select 'ok' from dual where 1 = nvl(1, 'X');
```

The Oracle documentation for `NVL` says:

> If expr1 is numeric, then Oracle determines which argument has the highest numeric precedence, implicitly converts the other argument to that datatype, and returns that datatype.

The values for `NLS_COMP`, `NLS_SORT` and `NLS_LANGUAGE` are the same between the two databases, so they shouldn't be causing a difference in the numeric precedence of the 2 arguments.  What could be different between these two databases to cause one to return `'ok'` and one to error?

Comment: are they the same versions, are they on the same server, do you connect to them through the same client from the same client machine?

Comment: They are both 12.1.0.2.0 (server and client versions match).  They are on different servers.  In both cases I am connecting with SQL Developer 3.2.20.10.  However, I am not connecting to them from the same client PC.

Comment: I ran a test, and "select nvl(1, '1') from dual" works, but "select nvl(1, 'X') from dual" does not.  According to the oracle docs it should never work if the 1st parameter is numeric, and the second parameter cannot be represented as a number.

Comment: Are those NLS settings the same in the SQL Developer sessions from both PCs (check SQL Dev settings, or query `nls_session_parameters`), or are you looking at the default database-level settings? Has either database had any patches applied since the .2 patchset?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I would think it should never work as well, but I actually have several servers that are living proof that it can work.  I just need to find out why.

Comment: @AlexPoole Those NLS settings are from `show parameter NLS_x` which I think is the same as querying `nls_session_parameters` (?).

Comment: @hmqcnoesy: actually the docs explain why `nvl(1,'1')` vs `nvl(1,'X')` behave differently. it's the point: "highest numeric precedence".  From the docs:  "If expr1 is numeric, then Oracle determines which argument has the highest numeric precedence, implicitly converts the other argument to that datatype, and returns that datatype."

Comment: @Ditto, your comment should be for OldProgrammer

Comment: @hmqcnoesy:  you may be right ... ;)

Comment: @hmqcnoesy - yes that is the same. Are there any patches applied? Or any odd init parameters (e.g. any starting with an underscore) which might have been set based on a support request? It may be something you need to raise an SR to track down if you can't find any differences.

Comment: @AlexPoole Unfortunately I don't have permission to find which if any patches have been applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cursor_sharing is likely the key factor.

The predicate "1 = nvl(1, 'X')" can be evaluated at parse time if it will always be executed as literals and optimized as either true or false. However if cursor_sharing is force then all three literals can be substituted for other values and the expression can't be evaluated until execution.

I had to use two separate local tables to test it.

```
alter session set cursor_sharing=force;
create table me_dual as select * from dual;
select 'ok' from me_dual x where 1 = nvl(1, 'A');
select 'ok' from me_dual x where 1 = nvl(1, 'A')

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
                                               *
alter session set cursor_sharing=exact;
create table alt_dual as select * from dual;
select 'ok' from alt_dual x where 1 = nvl(1, 'A');

'O
--
ok
```

Answer (score 5):

wrapping the column parameter for NVL within '*to_char*' resolved my issue with the 'ORA-01722: invalid number' error:

```
select 'ok' from dual where 1 = nvl(to_char(1), 'X');
```

Answer (score 1):

I know many are facing issue like **NVL: INVALID NUMBER in NVL Function** in Oracle Database.

```
SELECT NVL(1,'X') FROM dual;
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Here's the explantion and solution

Oracle implicitly converts the second argument in `NVL()` to same datatype as the first argument. For more information please [dig here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm).

So, the solution is to convert the first argument to char datatype using `to_char()`

```
SELECT NVL(to_char(1), 'X') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's cute ... this isn't an answer, but I can't post this in comments with any sort of readable clarity.

This is all run on same instance (oracle 11) ... but I think it shows similar issue.

```
  SQL> select version from v$instance;

  VERSION
  -----------------
  11.2.0.4.0

  SQL> select * from dual where 1 = nvl(1,'X');

  D
  -
  X

  SQL> select nvl(1,'X') from dual;
  select nvl(1,'X') from dual
               *
  ERROR at line 1:
  ORA-01722: invalid number


  SQL>
```

I recall seeing this before, but can't remember how to explain it.  O.o

Not sure why it seems to evaluate NVL differently between WHERE and SELECT clauses.